# How to use d3.js and .csv to draw a (daily, weekly, monthly, yearly) weather chart

Tags: csv, charts, d3.js, weather

Good morning!

I'm looking for a way to visualise the data from my weather station with d3.js. I'm collecting daily, weekly, monthly and yearly .csv-files like this:

```
01.01.2013,00:00,8.4,84,0.0,19.8,168,9,7.2
01.01.2013,00:30,7.8,89,0.9,18.1,156,9,7.3
01.01.2013,01:00,7.8,90,1.8,21.6,139,9,7.5
01.01.2013,01:30,8.0,90,2.4,18.3,126,9,7.6
01.01.2013,02:00,8.0,89,3.0,22.0,167,9,7.4
[...]
```

Right now I'm using pChart to create the charts, but its taking like forever for the monthly or even the weekly reports to load.

Id like to have charts like this:

[*klick* -> image: weekly chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wsjc.png)

but I'm really stuck at the moment, can't get the .csv loaded the right way as it seems.

I already ha a look on [Multi-Series Line Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/3884955), changed

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
```

to

```
d3.csv.parseRows("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
```

because I don't have headings in my .csv-files

Would you help me out here?

Thanks a lot!